# What should we do when a question is getting a lot of redundant answers?

Tags: discussion, popularity

Time to time I see questions that are rather old that have a lot of repeated answers.

In general the repeated answers were posted at the same time, so that makes sense. But some after a while start getting duplicate answers, that don't add anything new.

In some cases it even looks like the answered didn't care to read the previous answers because they are complete duplicates.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065598/if-a-folder-does-not-exist-create-it) is an example of what I am saying. It was posted in 2012, and has some 2014 answers that are just duplicates of the original ones.

**What should we do in these cases?** Should we flag the duplicate answers? (I don't know what flag would be appropriate, if so)

Comment: This is admittedly annoying, but unless an answer is obviously plagiarized we should leave it alone.  But ideally a question might be locked after it gets 3 or more dupe answers

Comment: You can also **protect** such questions if they appear to be gathering such answers recently (15K rep IIRC) from new users. If you don't have the rep, you could flag a moderator asking for it or bring it up in chat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick skim through some of those newer answers and I can already see some that are really just confirmations of the older ones rather than being answers in their own right, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065598/if-a-folder-does-not-exist-create-it/27979608#27979608) which basically says "Yeah that's all you really need".

Feel free to flag late answers that simply duplicate really old ones without adding any value; just make sure you explain this thoroughly and provide a link to the original answer so that it's easy to get to. Some of these answers, as I mentioned, don't actually serve as answers, so they really do nothing but clutter the question unnecessarily and should be removed. However, although these are non-answers, flagging as "not an answer" is not recommended unless they very obviously say "this worked for me thanks" or something along those lines. Use the "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)" flag option instead and describe it as above.

Keep in mind that just because an answer duplicates another doesn't always mean it doesn't add any value; for example, there can be more than one way to explain the same concept or even the same line(s) of code. On the other hand, we really don't need people bumping the same question with the same "use this [code]" answer every few months when that same code has already been sitting at the top of the answer list the whole time.

Comment: Wouldn't it be useful if a special purpose flag existed in order to address this issue?

Comment: @Dzyann: Not really - this is actually quite an edge case compared to what's currently covered in the flag dialog.

Comment: So basically you would flag for moderator attention and explain what you suggested?

Comment: @Dzyann: Pretty much.

Comment: @BoltClock is this still recommended behaviour for answers like this? This question was closed in favour of an older one but the dupe target doesn't have an authoritative answer. I'm looking at answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/1255289) and there are redundant answers posted 4-10 years later that don't add anything. Is flagging acceptable? Too many upvotes to take to SOCVR.

Comment: @miken32: Yes, you may continue to flag late answers that don't add anything but clutter. There are some answers with delete votes, and an answer was just delete-voted a few hours ago. For this specific question, I'd leave alone anything that's at least +10.

Comment: Thanks, can I suggest swapping the closure of this question with the dupe target so that this can act as the canonical answer to the question? (And sorry, I just saw your note about the +10, already flagged one over that.)